Parse value from JSON Input message with special char format
I'm expected to read the value of where(key = Canonical message)
and the value format is combination of many fields where I expected the read 'casetTitle' value in the Payload section mentioned below and set a property
using JsonSlurper()
Input JsoN
    {
        "Id": "db338737-af14-ef11-9f8a-000d3aad8ef7",
        "InputParameters": [
            {
           
                "key": "CanonicalMessage",
                "value": "{\"ActivityId\":\"9f368268\",\"Payload\":{\"CaseTitle\":\"Material Description 000\",\"CustomerAssetNumber\":\"104628\"}}"
            }
            
            {
                   "key": "transactionlogid",
                    "value": "9f36828e9"
            }
        ]
        
         }

how this be achieved through using JsonSlurper()?
Thank you very much
Yours sincerely
Sateesh

Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

It'd look something like the following.  Keep in mind I had to escape the quote escape sequence because I inlined this into a String literal.  Otherwise the language was interpret \" -> " and create invalid JSON.  If you were reading this from input you wouldn't need to do that.  This is just an artifact of this example; not real world code.
import groovy.json.*

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText("""
   {
        "Id": "db338737-af14-ef11-9f8a-000d3aad8ef7",
        "InputParameters": [
            {
                "key": "CanonicalMessage",
                "value": "{\\"ActivityId\\":\\"9f368268\\",\\"Payload\\":{\\"CaseTitle\\":\\"Material Description 000\\",\\"CustomerAssetNumber\\":\\"104628\\"}}"
            },
            {
                "key": "transactionlogid",
                "value": "9f36828e9"
            }
        ]
        
    }
""")

List<String> caseTitles = json.InputParameters
   .findAll { it.key == "CanonicalMessage" }
   .collect { 
      def innerJson = slurper.parseText( it.value )
      innerJson.Payload.CaseTitle
   }

println(caseTitles)


This is executable and works.

thank you, I want this  'CaseTitle' value to property.

@Sateesh I don't understand.  What do you mean by "'CaseTitle' value to property"?

what I mean store CaseTitle value to the Property

@Sateesh Store the CaseTitle to a variable?  You have the list just do String castTitle = caseTitles.first() to get the first element of the list.
